# Set Variable From Multidimensional $_POST Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to set a variable equal to one of the sub-arrays of my $_POST variable.

```
$array[] = $_POST['contact-info'];
echo $array['email'];
```

It won't work though as it echoes NULL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: show `print_r($_POST)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need square brackets for assigning this sub-array to a variable.

```
$array = $_POST['contact-info'];
echo $array['email'];
```

Comment: did you use print_r($_POST);?

Comment: in that case `print_r($_POST)` its not what you think it is

Comment: I could `echo $_POST['contact-info']['email'];` but I'm looking for a way to simplify the $_POST variable down to it's subcomponent arrays.

Comment: @MrGrinst yes, do `print_r($_POST);` and paste it's result here.

Comment: `Array
(
    [contact-info] => Array
        (
            ['name'] => Array
                (
                    ['first'] => 
                    ['middle'] => 
                    ['last'] => 
                )
            ['email'] => 
            ['phone'] => 
            ['address'] => Array
                (
                    ['street'] => 
                    ['po'] => 
                    ['city'] => 
                    ['state'] => 
                    ['zip'] => 
                )
        )
)`

Comment: You see nothing is coming in the posted data. `['email']` is blank. No other is data is coming though. You need to check your form and code. And it will be `echo $array['name']['email'];` not `echo $array['email'];`

Comment: Even when I enter data in and get it to output to print_r like so: `Array ( [contact-info] => Array ( ['name'] => Array ( ['first'] => ['middle'] => ['last'] => ) ['email'] => test@example.com ['phone'] => ['address'] => Array ( ['street'] => ['po'] => ['city'] => ['state'] => ['zip'] => ) ) )`, it still doesn't output the other way.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST simply is not a multi dimensional array. `echo print_r($_POST,1);` will show you what is exactly in $_POST. When used, $_POST will always be populated for you by PHP with key (string) - value (string) pairs. If $_POST does contain sub arrays, then it's probably populated by you yourself or by some framework you are using.

For now I'm guessing that `contact-info` is the form name of the form you are submitting. The form name is not of importance when reading out the submitted form. You can directly access the sent data through the name of the field sent..

For example, if you had:

```
<form name="contact-info" action="yourscript.php" method="post">
  Please enter your e-mail address:<br/>
  <input name="email" type="text" value="" />
</form>
```

Then in your php script you should have:

```
<?php
  echo "You just entered: " . $_POST['email']; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$array['email']` is never set. You set the array like this:

`$array[] = $_POST['contact-info'];`

So assuming that was the first time you've used `$array` then you would access email by:

`echo $array[0]['email'];`

If you don't need `$array` to be multi-dimensional, You could always just do:

```
$array = $_POST['contact-info'];
echo $array['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere, the email is currently empty. The structure of the array should match the form so, if your form is

```
name="contact-info[email]"
```

Then in PHP you would access that as

```
$contact_info = $_POST['contact-info'];
$email = $contact_info['email'];
```

OR

```
$email = $_POST['contact-info']['email'];
```

Also, try this for a little more clarity when debugging an array, it makes spoting the associations easier.

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
</pre>
```